# Не открывается скомпилированный файл с помощью Nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

Мои аргументы: `nuitka --mingw64 --windows-disable-console --windows-icon-from-ico=objection.ico --windows-company-name=Objection.lol --windows-product-name=Objection.lolClient --windows-file-version=1.0.1 --exe --follow-imports --windows-file-description=Client. --run myscript1.0.1.py`

Файл сам просто выдает exe и cmd больше ничего, они просто ничего не делают. Вот терминал логи: [image: введите сюда код]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--enable-plugin=pyqt5` и проверьте модули -_-