# Как скомпилировать файл в nuitka чтобы он запускался в фоне?

Tags: python, c++, c, nuitka

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать скрипт в питоне, который должен запускаться в фоновом режиме.
Если запускать просто через питон исходник, то все работает. Я компилирую его через nuitka такой командой:

```
nuitka --windows-disable-console --follow-imports --enable-plugin=pyqt5 --jobs=4 main.py
```

Все успешно компилируется, кроме строки

```
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: pyqt5: Not relevant with this OS, or Nuitka arguments given, not activated.
```

Вот полный вывод в консоль:

```
Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --windows-disable-console --follow-imports --enable-plugin=pyqt5 --jobs=4 main.py
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: pyqt5: Not relevant with this OS, or Nuitka arguments given, not activated.
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '1.8.6' on Python '3.11' commercial grade 'not installed'.
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: cl (cl 14.3).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend linking program with 254 files (no progress information available for this stage).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Compiled 254 C files using clcache with 252 cache hits and 2 cache misses.
Nuitka:INFO: Keeping build directory 'main.build'.
Nuitka:INFO: Successfully created 'main.exe'.
Nuitka:INFO: Execute it by launching 'main.cmd', the batch file needs to set environment.

C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\test>
```

Но после компиляции, при запуске скрипта ничего не происходит (В диспетчере задач не появляется никаких процессов и скрипт не выполняет то что должен сделать)

У скрипта нет никакого графического интерфейса.
Система: windows 10
Если в cmd выполнить main.exe то ничего не произойдет:

```
C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\test>main.exe

C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\test>
```

Мне надо, чтобы скрипт запустился без консоли или других окон.
Пытался найти решение, но в основном натыкался на такие [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442211/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-nuitka).
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Скомпилировал недавно `.exe` с `pyQt6` используя команду `nuitka --windows-disable-console h14.py` и всё нормально работает‍♀️